# On Mouse Click for "OnTriggerStay" to Add Score, Adds More Than Set Amount

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Short and simple, object drops into trigger object, I click, score goes up. Score is set to +1, adds +2 to +5, no reasonable explanation (script and video provided)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int currentScore;
    public Text displayScore;
    public int addScore;

    void OnTriggerStay ()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            currentScore += addScore;
        }
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        displayScore.text = currentScore.ToString();
    }
}
```

[Video, goes to Youtube](https://youtu.be/gZzWvT11uB4)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, what exactly is calling the OnTriggerStay() function, because that is not the Unity function it should be like this:

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        currentScore += addScore;
    }
}
```

also note that if you use OnTrigger the ball must have a Rigidbody, other than that GetMouseButtonDown(0) should work as expected and  worked fine for my tests.

My only explanation here is that the other script or any script changes currentScore, you can test that by setting the var private.

Edit:

i think i know your problem, i presume that multiple collider trigger the function so it is called multiple times per frame, since it's the same frame `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` is true for each collider.
You should therefore add a check to the if case

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && col.name.Equals("Yoyo")){
...
}
```

i presume that the ball is called yoyo ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work. I'm not sure why this issue is happening. Tried alternating, increasing and decreasing amounts, yet nothing. I live in Spain without the s :/

Comment: the code snippet itself is fine if you use it with Collider, otherwise you call the function yourself, so look if something else is changing it. Other problem could be that your mouse is giving up and that it counts holding down as multiple presses. but i guess you would have noticed that on other applications.
Just to make sure, you are holding down your mouse, right? or do you want to count the ball only once as long as it is inside the trigger, no matter how often you press the mouse.

Comment: nah, seems to be at random. I tried holding down the mouse, clicking it quickly. Numbers are still randomized. I plan on doing the one click one trigger method, if that helps at all.

Comment: do you have a MWE to take a look?

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge, but what is an MWE?

Comment: [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example)

Comment: I believe the video link I provided at the bottom of my original post would suffice, unless you'd like to take a look at the project file, in which case I could send it to you.

Comment: yeah of course, can't really debug with that video ;), gotta go sleep now tho. If you have the MWE i can look at it tomorrow

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/111oi8DKxqq9woUKiwYUtVu1o8FoE3FC-/view?usp=sharing hopefully this helps

Comment: i can't seem to reproduce your error shown in the video, when i click the yoyo it goes up. if i click it while it is inside the 1Point area it counts +1 and only +1 seems to work as intended

Comment: And as usual I strike out in programming. Although very good idea, the edit post ceased to make any difference. Although I seem to be in a rut, and it apparently is just a problem on my pc's end, I suppose there's not much else to do. Thank you for your cooperation.